# What am I doing wrong in this Parcelable class?

Tags: android, parcelable

I'm trying to start a new Activity and add a custom Parcelable object to the Intent.
Apparently this does not work:

Class:

```
public class TestObject implements Parcelable{

private String mString;
private int mInt;
private List<String> mList;



public TestObject() {
    this.mString = "This is a String";
    this.mInt = 777;
    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        mList.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
}




public TestObject(Parcel in) {
    setmInt(in.readInt());
    setmString(in.readString());
    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    in.readStringList(mList);

}


public void setmString(String mString) {
    this.mString = mString;
}



public void setmInt(int mInt) {
    this.mInt = mInt;
}


public String getmString() {
    return mString;
}




public int getmInt() {
    return mInt;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}






@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(mString);
    dest.writeInt(mInt);
    dest.writeStringList(mList);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public TestObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new TestObject(in); 
    }

    public TestObject[] newArray(int size) {
        return new TestObject[size];
    }
};
```

}

FirstActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TestObject object = new TestObject();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    Debug.startMethodTracing("parcelable");
    i.putExtra("object", object);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Second Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    TestObject ob = (TestObject) i.getParcelableExtra("object");
    Debug.stopMethodTracing();
    Log.d("object string", "string: " + ob.getmString());

}
```

The problem is with the `List<String>`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you write the variables to the Parcel in a different order than you read them. You write mString first but read mInt first. This will work:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(mString);
    dest.writeInt(mInt);
    dest.writeStringList(mList);
}

public TestObject(Parcel in) {
    setmString(in.readString());
    setmInt(in.readInt());
    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    in.readStringList(mList);
}
```

And btw don't use a raw type for the CREATOR, use this instead:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<TestObject> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<TestObject>() {
        public TestObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new TestObject(in); 
        }

        public TestObject[] newArray(int size) {
            return new TestObject[size];
        }
    };
```